# Understanding the assumptions of different SHAP Methods

Tags: python, shap

I am interested in applying SHAP values to some work I am doing in machine learning, and notice that there are a number of different methods one can pick from on the github page: https://github.com/slundberg/shap

I have a neural network model, so as far as I understand I can use the functions: DeepExplainer, GradientExplainer or KernelExplainer. I am aware that DeepExplainer is based on DeepLift, and GradientExplainer is based on integrated gradients, but I am really struggling to find a clear outline of the assumptions each method makes. **Is anyone able to clear up what assumptions each of these methods make, or point me in the direction of a source for this?**

To be clear, I am not talking about the specific speed of each, I am considering the following points: Do any of them assume some property of the model? Do they assume inputs are independent? Which are appropriate for a mix of one-hot encoded and continuous variables? In short I cannot find a clear reference for this, or even a clear reference for what the GradientExplainer algorithm is even doing.

Comment: They have `notebooks` folder where each algo is clearly explained, and python version for the explainer is showed. If it's not enough you may go through source code. In addition, SHAP package looks like a Python project to support research that's published on arXiv by Scott Lundberg et al